# How to create a wordpress template without using any page

Tags: templates, page-template

I'm not sure WordPress was build for this, but this is what I'm trying to achieve:

- I want to make a specific URL inside wordpress accessible, for example `www.example.com/some-template` .
- This specific URL should be editable from a  php file, part of an existing wordpress theme I'm working on, something like `some-template.php`)
- This is the tricky part: I don't want wordpress users to be able to see or use this template from the custom templates dropdown menu when editing a page. I don't want a specific page to exist in order for this to work. This template should work without any page (I'm not interested in creating a page and hiding it, or hiding the template).

The reason I'm trying to do this, is that I want to have a specific template that pieces together a few pages and menus from wordpress and creates some kind of a 'custom view' which is pulled every few hours to another site. It's all part of a bigger picture (the details are not that important).

While searching, I only found out that it's possible to create custom templates for at least one page, but then that page must exist in wordpress for the template to work.

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `template_redirect` action:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse131387_template_redirect' );
function wpse131387_template_redirect( ){
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/some-template') {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;
        status_header(200);
        include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/some-template.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with using fischi's solution although I believe your could work as well.

Comment: @ShaharDekel Welcome! With this solution you keep everything in your theme and there is no need to touch .htaccess.

Comment: Use the filter `template_include` instead: https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/

Comment: I'm not sure, But after some tests, I think `template_include` effects performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the very simple way, putting your file `some-template.php` in the root directory of your WordPress install.

Adding this to your `.htaccess` will use the `some-template.php` for the url `www.mysite.com/some-template`

```
RewriteRule ^some-template$ ./some-template.php$1
```

In your `some-template.php` you load WordPress, including `wp-load.php`

```
include('wp-load.php');
//all your custom goodies
```

Now you have access to all WordPress functions, and you do not need to have a page in the database.

Please be aware that if someone creates a page `some-template`, you may get an error, as the page is not visible due to your custom file.

Comment: Your RewriteRule should probably look more like `RewriteRule ^some-template(.*)$ ./some-template.php$1`. That way the `$1` has something to refer back to.

Comment: Interesting idea, I might try it. I could get over the page creation problem by restricting users from creating a page with that specific name.

Comment: @patj you are right, but actually it would be better not to add the $1 in the first place ;-) my mistake.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of waffled on which one you meant, and chose wrong.